# When is the product of two points on a circle is still on the circle?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Suppose we have a pair $(x,y)\in\Bbb{R}^2$ such that $x^2+y^2=1$. I want to find a pair $(a,b)$ such that $a^2+b^2=1$ and $(xa)^2+(yb)^2=1$. What is $a$ and $b$ in terms of $x$ and $y$?

Comment: You get $x^2b^2 + y^2 a^2 = 0$. If $x \ne 0$ and $y \ne 0$ then you cannot find such $a,b$.

Comment: How do I get this equality?

Comment: Subtract the third equality from the first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given $x^2+y^2=1$ and $a^2+b^2=1$, multiplying, we have $(xa)^2+(yb)^2+(xb)^2+(ya)^2=1$

Now if we also have $(xa)^2+(yb)^2=1$, we must have $(xb)^2+(ya)^2=0$.  So what could satisfy this as well as be on the unit circle?

---

Addition:
For $(xb)^2+(ya)^2=0$, we must have both $xb, ya = 0$.  However one among $(a^2, b^2)$ must be $1$, and similarly for $(x^2, y^2)$.  Hence we have solutions
$(a, b) = (\pm1, 0)$ when $(x, y) = (\pm1, 0)$ and
$(a, b) = (0, \pm1)$ when $(x, y) = (0, \pm1)$

Comment: But wolfram alpha says that there are other solutions as well: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28xb%29%5E2%2B%28ya%29%5E2%3D0%2C+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1%2C+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3D1

Comment: You need to use http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28xb%29%5E2%2B%28ya%29%5E2%3D0%2C+x%5E2%2By%5E2%3D1%2C+a%5E2%2Bb%5E2%3D1%2C+Reals to avoid complex solutions.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG assume that $x,y,a,b\ge 0$ otherwise we consider $-x,-y...$ etc.Now applying Cauchy-Schwarz inequality we get $(x^2+y^2)(a^2+b^2)\ge (ax+by)^2$ now from the given condition it reduces to $2abxy\le 0$ and since we assumed them to be $\ge 0$ at least one of them is equal to $0$.so let $x=0$ hence $|y|=1$ and since $(xa)^2+(yb)^2=1$ we have $|b|=1$ and this implies $a=0$. so the solutions are $(x,y,a,b)=(0,\pm{1},0,\pm{1})$ or $(\pm{1},0,\pm{1},0)$ considering ordered pairs.

Answer (score 0):

WLOG, let $a=\cos C,b=\sin C$ and $x=\cos D,y=\sin D$

$$(xa)^2+(yb)^2=1\iff \cos^2D\cos^2C+\sin^2D\sin^2C=1 $$

$$\frac{1+\cos2D}2\cdot \frac{1+\cos2C}2+\frac{1-\cos2D}2\cdot \frac{1-\cos2C}2=1$$

$$\implies2+2\cos2C\cos2D=4\implies \cos2C\cos2D=1$$

As $-1\le\cos2C,\cos2D\le1$ we need $\cos2C=\cos2D=\pm1$

Now,

$\cos2C=1\iff 2\cos^2C-1=1\iff\cos C=\pm1$

$\cos2C=-1\iff 2\cos^2C-1=-1\iff\cos C=0$